# JQuery not serializing fom Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, serialization

I have the following PHP code:

```
echo '      <td id="'.$metaso['semanaventa'].'td1"><form id="'.$metaso['semanaventa'].'form" name="'.$metaso['semanaventa'].'form" class="dinamic" action="compromiso_funciones.php"  method="post">
<input type="text" id="'.$metaso['semanaventa'].'txt" name="met_aso_venta" value="" style="width:100px;" tabindex="'.($idx + 1).'" class="validate[required,custom[number]] moneda" />
<input type="text" style="display:none;" name="met_aso_pr" value="'.$metaso['asociado'].'" />
<input type="text" style="display:none;" name="semana" value="'.$metaso['semanaventa'].'" />
<input type="submit"  class ="boton" style="margin:0px;width:100px; display:none;" id="'.$metaso['asociado'].$metaso['semanaventa'].'btn" name="'.$metaso['asociado'].$metaso['semanaventa'].'btn" value="Actualizar" /></form></td>';
echo '      <td id="'.$metaso['semanaventa'].'td2"></td>';
```

And this is the JQuery Script:

```
            $('.dinamic').live("submit",(function(){
            if ( $(this).validationEngine('validate')){
                $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(html){

                });
            }
            return false; 
        }));
```

This works fine on FF, Chrome, Opera **but Any IE version.**

I've found that:

```
$(this).serialize();
```

**Returns nothing.**

I've tried the malsup form plugin, a manual serializing by using JQ's .each function etc..

Help!!!!

Comment: What version of jquery are you running?

Comment: **1.4.4** Tried 1.6.4(latest) and nothing

Comment: Is the generated HTML in FF / Chrome validating? IE gets tripped up if the HTML isn't correct.

Comment: **Only warnings** with the FF html validator

Comment: Not sure submit can be binded with live :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved it!!**

Before entering to the validation function, I serialized the form and passed it to the post function.

Hope this helps your future problems.

Look for the **serial** var, it does the magic.

**THANKS EVERYONE**

```
            $('.dinamic').live("submit",(function(){
            forma = $(this);
            serial = $(forma).serialize();
            forma= $(forma).attr('id');
            reng = forma.substring(0,6);
            if ( $(this).validationEngine('validate')){
                $('#' + reng + 'td2').empty().html('<img src="imgs/exito.png" />');
                $('#' + reng + 'td1').html($('#' + reng +'txt').val());
                $.post($(this).attr("action"), serial, function(html){

                });
            }//Cierre Validate
            return false; // prevent normal submit
        }));
```

Comment: I've had this problem since ever!!!! I hate IE :(
Before entering anything the data should be serialized first, then everything works fine. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using submit() instead of live?

http://jsfiddle.net/Av4hW/1/

Seems to work fine :)

Comment: I can't since my data is dinamically generated so I have to bind the event this way.